# Google says the app does not comply with its policy. I can't find any shortcomings

Tags: android, publish, google-play-console, policy

I am sharing google play app for the first time. I got rejected a few times. I noticed very important issues and made their arrangements. But for a few days I am getting the same error.

I'm definitely **not using** `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />` permission.

Manifest looks like this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

**Google claims to me that location permission is not policy compliant. Here is the message**

[image]

İ don't know how to fix it.
If you could help with this situation, I would greatly appreciate it.

### EDIT

Doesn't that mean it's the privacy policy? The following photo appears before the application asks for location permission. Google denied this. In the permission text, there is a direction on the [backendd.com](http://backendd.com) site.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might confuse *Google's* policy with *your* **privacy policy**.

It seems that your privacy policy infomation is just shortcoming but not permissions. Review your privacy policy and revise it enough to match the location permissions.

The privacy policy is the one whose URL is specified in `App content > Privacy Policy` of your app on Google Play Console.

[image: screenshot]

You should publish your privacy policy on the web page of the URL.

Comment: Can you provide information about what my privacy policy is?

Comment: @EminNiftiyev No, I can't. It's your decision about what it is. But the compliance check list states these points. Basically expressing all of these points in your privacy policy may perhaps comply to the Google's requirement.

Comment: so what I want to say is this as an article, as a video? Plus I don't know where to add it. Is it in the program, has google reserved a forum for it? I don't know these details.

Comment: @EminNiftiyev It's not inside of your app but on the Play Console. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your privacy policy. Just add lines about location data you are getting.

Comment: where should i add privacy police? in theProgram? or Forum?  I have no knowledge about this.